# 分割したDataframeを複数のファイルに分けてCSVで出力したい

Tags: python, csv

図のようなデータに対して、IDごとにDataframeを分割（for df_i in dfs）し、分割したDataframeをそれぞれCSVファイルに出力したい考えております。

しかし、アプトプットのファイルを見ると最後にLoopされたIDした出力されません。
どのようにすれば、各DataframeをCSVで出力できますでしょうか。

```
# フォルダを指定
infolder = './'
outfolder = './'

# ファイル名の組み立て方情報(特定文字列+数字の形式の場合)
fprefix = 'list'       # ファイル名の頭に付いている文字列
fsuffixFirst = 1       # ファイル名に付いている最初の数字
fsuffixMaxPlus1 = 5 # ファイル名に付いている最大の数字に+1したもの
fsuffixStep  = 1       # ファイル名に付いている数字の増えていく間隔

# データフレームをスライスしたい場合
k = 3
n = data.shape[0]
dfs = [data.loc[i:i+k-1, :] for i in range(0, n, k)]

#CSVファイルへ書き出す
for fsuffix in range(fsuffixFirst, fsuffixMaxPlus1, fsuffixStep):
    basefname = fprefix + str(fsuffix)         # ファイル名だけ部分の組み立て
    inputfile = infolder + basefname + '.csv'  # パス名作成
    for  df_i in dfs:　#データフレーム分割
        df_i.to_csv(outfolder + basefname + '_0.5h.csv', index=False)
```

**各IDの週データ**

[image: 各IDの週データ]

Comment: `for fsuffix in range(...` と `for df_i in dfs` で二重ループにしてしまっている事が原因です。最低限の変更で済ませるのであれば、`for df_i in dfs: df_i.to_csv(outfolder + basefname + '_0.5h.csv', index=False)` を `dfs[fsuffix-1].to_csv(outfolder + basefname + '_0.5h.csv', index=False)` にすればよろしいかと。

Comment: @metropolis
こちらご教示いただき誠にありがとうございます。
変更する箇所も最小限で大変助かりました。
ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1):

```py
for index, id in enumerate(data['ID'].unique()):
    tmp_data = data[data['ID'] == id]
    tmp_data.to_csv(outfolder + fprefix + str(index+1) + '_0.5h.csv', index=False)
```

こんな感じでいいと思いますけど、どうでしょう？`df.unique()`でIDの一覧を取得して、そのIDの行のみを抽出して（`data[data['ID'] == id]`）、連番をつけてファイルに出力しています。

Comment: `df.unique()`でIDの一覧を取得して、`data[data['ID'] == id]`にする発想がなかったので大変勉強になりました。
コードもスマートで大変わかりやすいです。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 0):

以下は `pandas.DataFrame.groupby()` を使う方法です。

```py
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({
  'ID': [10, 10, 10, 20, 20, 20, 30, 30, 30, 40, 40, 40],
  'name': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'D'],
  'week': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3],
  '売上': [100, 200, 300, 50, 60, 70, 1, 2, 3, 500, 600, 700],
}) 

#フォルダを指定
outfolder = './'

# ファイル名の組み立て方情報(特定文字列+数字の形式の場合)
fprefix = 'list'       # ファイル名の頭に付いている文字列

for i, (id, group) in enumerate(data.groupby('ID')):
  group.to_csv(f'{outfolder}{fprefix}{i+1}_0.5h.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: 大変わかりやすいコードで理解を深めることができました。`data_groupby()`で対応できるという点が新たな発見でした。
こちらご対応いただきありがとうございました。